# C# multiple DownloadString in loop, 500 error

Tags: c#, html, http, request, downloadstring

Basically what i am doing is trying to get a bunch of HTML links from a HTML page.

First i download the HTML Page as a string. I then search that string for a bunch of HTML links and stick them into a list which is then displayed in the app. That all works fine.

Next i need to download each one of those HTML links in the list as a string, and again search for more HTML links and stick those into a list as well. But i am getting a "500 internal server error".

Here is the code for the first DownloadString:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
data = client.DownloadString(URLMain);
client.Dispose();
```

The HTML links are identified from the data and stuck into a list. I am then using this code to loop through and download each link:

```
WebClient client2 = new WebClient();
for (int i = 1; i <= listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    data = client2.DownloadString(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());

    //Search data for HTML link, stick link into list, clear data, and repeat X times.
}
```

Im not really sure what im doing wrong. Kinda new to C#. But as mentioned in just getting a 500 internal server error on the second part of code. Maybe im requesting too fast? Any help would be much appreciated as this is my last hurdle in completing this program.

--------------UPDATE

Ok i have some progress. I rewrote the download loop differently using some source code i found on the web. "Start Multiple Async Tasks and Process Them As They Complete"

I am no longer getting a 500 server error, and i am able to download multiple stuff without getting errors. But i suspect that there is something wrong with the URLs. I am not getting the data that i should be receiving.

I tried setting the list of URLs to the same main URL which is "kissanime.com/Anime/Accel-World" and that returns the correct html as a string. So i know that the download request is working fine.

But when the url is this "kissanime.com/Anime/Accel-World/Episode-001?id=4609" it doesn't return the data it should return. Instead it returns this: http://pastebin.com/C9vH01Lc

Although when i try that exact link in a browser it opens fine to the correct page.
I have also tried changing the links to "kissanime.com/Anime/Accel-World/Episode-001" which still produces the same results.

So something is wrong with the URLs. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the value of `listBox1.Items[i].ToString()`?

Comment: Its the HTML links grabbed from the previous DownloadString. An example of a link "http://kissanime.com/Anime/Accel-World/Episode-024?id=4622"

Comment: If that's the exact string, try prepending it with an `http://` as well.

Comment: It does have http:// for some reason when i pasted the link here it removed it :S

Comment: Interesting.  If you paste the exact string into your browser, does it work?  I'd also like to double-check that this is the actual string being used.  Are you assuming this is the string because it's the contents of the list box, or are you debugging this and actually examining the runtime value of `listBox1.Items[i].ToString()`?  (That is, do you put a debugging breakpoint there and enter that line into the command window in the debugger to make sure?)

Comment: Well i have a messagebox just before the downloadstring command which shows the string being used. And it is the exact same. Also if i have a look at the bottom in the debugger after the break the link is also the same.

Comment: Can you check all the links that is sent to the WebClient, in your browser? The webclient uses a Get Request when it is an http, and your browser will also invoke the Get request as well. So if you are seeing a 500 response from the server, your browser should say the same. Do let me know.

Comment: I have tried all the links in the browser and they all work.

Comment: It seems to be that once i make 1 request, all the other requests return 500 server errors.

Answer (score 1):

I bet some of those strings/links are using relative paths.

An example from stackoverflow web page:

```
<a href="/users/256728/black-frog" class="profile-link">Black Frog</a>
```

You will need to add the document base path to the relative path to get a complete Uri. Then you can download next resource.

You also mention in a comment above that the Uri works in a regular browser. Depending on the site, some sites throttle the number of requests that hits the same from the same ip address.  Try slowing down the request between each request by using `Thread.Sleep(5000)` to see what happens.

Comment: Yeah thats what im doing, the original links that are being grabbed look like this "/Anime/Accel-World/Episode-023?id=4605", im them adding this to the main URL before sticking into a list. And ive checked the contents of the list and tried each link in a browser and they all work fine. I have also just tried your second suggestion but still produces the same results.

Comment: I will have a solution for you later

Answer (score 0):

I FIGURED IT OUT :D

I had to add

```
httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");
```

And it now works :)

Thanks for everyone who helped and sorry if i wasted anyones time.